# React Native Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How do I get rid of this warning? I know I need to get rid of setState functions in the render method, but I need them, so where should I put them?

```
export default class List<T> extends React.PureComponent<ListProps<T>> {
state = { wrapped: false, iconName: "arrow-down" };

render(): React.Node {
    const { rows, renderRow, title, onPress } = this.props;
    if (this.state.wrapped === true) {
        list = undefined;
        this.setState({ iconName: "arrow-up" });
    } else {
        list = rows.map((row, index) => (
            <View key={index} style={index !== rows.length - 1 ? styles.separator : {}}>
                {renderRow(row, index)}
            </View>
        ));
        this.setState({ iconName: "arrow-down" });
    }
    return (
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={[styles.separator, styles.relative]}>
                    <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
                    <IconButton
                        style={styles.icon}
                        onPress={() => this.setState({ wrapped: !this.state.wrapped })}
                        name={this.state.iconName}
                        color="black"
                    />
                </View>
                {list}
            </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need to get rid of `setState` calls in your `render` method in general. You just need to put them so that they are not called in each render call (by binding them to user events like clicks for example) and thereby trigger another re-render, that again calls `setState` and again re-renders and so on.

So in your particular case, you are firing `setState` right in the beginning in the `if() { ... } else { ... }` statements. No matter what `this.state.wrapped` is, you end up at `setState`.

Here is a possible solution for how you might want to change your code specifically to make it what I assume you want it to make:

```
export default class List<T> extends React.PureComponent<ListProps<T>> {
state = { wrapped: false };

render(): React.Node {
    const { rows, renderRow, title, onPress } = this.props;
    const { wrapped } = this.state;

    return (
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={[styles.separator, styles.relative]}>
                    <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
                    <IconButton
                        style={styles.icon}
                        onPress={() => this.setState({ wrapped: !wrapped })}
                        name={wrapped ? "arrow-up" : "arrow-down"}
                        color="black"
                    />
                </View>
                {!wrapped && (
                  <View key={index} style={index !== rows.length - 1 ? styles.separator : {}}>
                    {renderRow(row, index)}
                  </View>
                )}
            </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
}}
```

Because the value of your icon is directly correlated to `wrapped`, you don't need to specifically set the icon in the state. Rather infer it from `wrapped`.